# autotools: why AX_... rather than AC_... in configure.ac?

Tags: macros, autotools

I came across a collection of autoconf macros today: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/The-Macros.html#The-Macros. All are prefixed `ax_` , e.g. `ax_ac_append_to_file.m4`, which is activated in `configure.ac` by including the line `AX_ABSOLUTE_HEADER()`.

In the past, I have only seen macros starting with `AC_`.

So is the switch to `AX_` a relatively new convention, a means of avoiding namespace collisions, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are namespaced. `AC_` refers to macros from Autoconf, `AM_` is Automake, `LT_` is Libtool, etc.

In the past it was common for other programs supplying macros to stomp all over Autoconf's namespace, which is why you might have seen variations on some of the `AX_` macros out in the wild with `AC_` prefixes.

Comment: This isn't clear. Is `AX_` for user-defined macros then?

Comment: `AX_` is not specific, it's just a convention. What matters is that it doesn't use one of the reserved namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

`AX_` is the standard "namespace" for autoconf-archive, to keep it from colliding with other implementations.

You'll find for instance my old `attributes.m4` copied and used in many places, and that uses the `CC_` prefix instead (because originally it checked the compiler only.)